# I got this Error '... inaccessible due to it's protection level'

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I've read a little about this problem but I didn't get any helpful answer, in my case I get the problem in the `if (!_positioner.GetPosition(ref position, _content, contentSize))` line where the error says that `FloatPositioner.GetPosition(ref ...)` is inaccessible due to its protection level:

```
using UnityEngine;


private GUIContent _content;
private FloatPositioner _positioner;

public string Text { get { return _content.text; } set { _content.text = value; } }
public GUIStyle Style {get; set;}

public void OnGUI()
{
    var position = new Vector2();
    var contentSize = Style.CalcSize(_content);
    if (!_positioner.GetPosition(ref position, _content, contentSize)) \\Right Here
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return;
    }


    GUI.Label(new Rect(position.x, position.y, contentSize.x, contentSize.y), _content, Style); 
}
```

On the other hand, I get this notification that I have to declare a body for `FloatPositioner.GetPosition` in order to run properly or something, but I don't really know what that is for. I assume it's the one causing the problem:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FloatPositioner : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool GetPosition(ref Vector2 position, GUIContent content, Vector2 size);
}
```

Help !

Comment: try making it `public` or use any other `access specifiers`

Comment: There can occasionally be confusing error messages, but this one is pretty clear. Can you explain what you're confused about?

Comment: Beginners guide when encountering an error while programming with Visual Studio: (1) Look for the error number in the compiler error message. In your case probably "CS0122" (2) Insert that number into your favourite search engine (3) The #1 hit will almost always be a link into the MSDN. Click it. (4) Read carefully (5) Fix your code accordingly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is Protection level when you are accessing bool GetPosition?
Your class is public but the method you are trying to call isn't.

```
public class FloatPositioner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool GetPosition(ref Vector2 position, GUIContent content, Vector2 size);
}
```

Comment: Oh my bad i didn't pay attention to the method when i was trying to call , thanks a bunch !